# Reset branch to earlier commit, want to make sure I undo pushed changes/merges correctly

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I went ahead and rushed to judgment to undo a bunch of commits using the "Reset" option in SourceTree. The commits were pushed to a Bare:master that I use to clone from. Now the reset repository is showing 11 pulls from the Bare:master.

A little history: I have source code that, when updated, I publish to Code.Publish. Prior to that I created the Bare:master so that I could have a clean repository. Any time the source code is updated, I publish to Code.Publish, then stage > commit > push to Bare:master. I clone Bare:master to three separate repositories (Code.Web1, Code.Web2, Code.Web3). When changes to the source are made to Code.Publish, I pull those changes into Code.Web1, etc.

I want to now undo the merges/pushes made to Bare:master from Code.Publish.

I gather from reading [THIS](http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html#pushed), that I can now just do `gitk --date-order` to determine the SHA of the commit I want to revert.  And then I would select that last BAD commit so as to keep the parent commit which is good. I just wanted to confirm that is correct.

Also, with respect to Code.Web1, etc., as I mentioned, I pulled the changes from Bare:master and they were merged into the repository. Should I just simply do the same thing I did with Code.Publish, in that I should just "Reverse" the commits to the last good one?

The changes I made were garbage, so I am not worried about these changes I want to reverse. And I just wanted to make sure I am ok with doing it this way. One of the things that is tripping me up with that link above is that the author comments that in the future merges may have problems.

Essentially, if I do it this way, and then later make changes to the Source which are then published to Code.Publish, will I run into serious problems?

No one else is using this code, so I am not worried that anyone else's code will be messed up.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are two main ways to undo a commit in Git.  The first, as you have described, is to use `git revert`, which reverses exactly what a previous commit did.  This method is totally safe to use on a published/shared remote branch because it just adds new commits to the branch.  The other option is to delete the bad commits using an interactive Git rebase or something along these lines.  This method is generally _not_ a good idea to use on a published/shared remote branch because it rewrites the history of the branch, which can cause big confusion and hassle for everyone.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, as far as I can tell "revert" (or reverse) is different than "reset", which is what I did. Also, as I mentioned, this is not a shared repository, so the issue of causing confusion/hassles is not a concern for me. I just want to make sure I do this "correctly" (let's leave whether I am doing it "right" for another day). :)

Comment: If you want to nuke `N` commits from the head of the `master` branch, then use `git reset --hard HEAD~N`.  I am not sure what SourceTree's reset does under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up getting the right answer through some additional research:

`git update-ref HEAD [SHA ID]`, where `[SHA ID]` is the ID of the commit I wanted to get back to.

I then did `git gc` and `git prune` to get rid of old references.